# Excel formula for a date column based on the date in other column

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Column A has been formatted to enter dates. I want column B auto filled with the date which is 10 days more than the dates in column A. So, I entered the Excel formula "=A2+10" in B2. Then copied the same formula in other cells in B column. The problem is, column B shows 01/10/00 when column A is empty.

| Col A | Col B |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/15/2022 | 5/25/2022 |  |
|  |  | I want the cell in Col B blank, when Col A is blank) |
|  |  | I want the cell in Col B blank, when Col A is blank) |
| 7/25/2022 | 8/4/2022 |  |
|  |  | I want the cell in Col B blank, when Col A is blank) |

I do not want to see any value in column B when column A is empty. How is that possible? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(A2="","",A2+10)
```

---

if the value in cell `A2` is empty `""` then it returns an empty else adds `10` to cell `A2`

Answer (score 2):

`=if( isblank(a2) ,"", A2+10 )`

This will give a blank appearance but allow you to still have a formula that calculates when col A is populated.